# requireJS - with ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

**index.html**

```
<link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-main="Scripts/app" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>

<a class="btn0">button 0</a>
<div class="target"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
require({
    paths : {
        jQuery : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min',
        tooltip : 'bootstrap-tooltip'
    }
});

require([ 'jQuery' ], function() {
    require(['tooltip' ], function() {
        $(".btn0").click(function() {
            $(".target").load('btn0.html');
        });

        $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
    });
});
```

**btn0.html**

```
 Wouldn't it be nice to see a Tooltip <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Oh yeah!">here</a>?
```

---

In this situation, the tooltip doesn't work. Only works if i cut `$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();` and paste in btn0.html like:

```
<script>
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
</script>
```

My question is. How organize the javascript code that is needed in btn0.html? It is possible put the JS content of btn0.html in app.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `tooltip()` function when btn0.html is loaded.
Element with `rel="tooltip"` does not exist when inicializing that page.

```
require([ 'jQuery' ], function() {
  require(['tooltip' ], function() {
    $(".btn0").click(function() {
      $(".target").load('btn0.html', function ()
      {
        $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
      })
    });
  });
});
```